# Confused with results with google maps API and my formula with distance matrix

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a project that will detect nearby markers/establishments based on the radius I set. I have `5km/3km/1km` selection. I temporarily set the center to a static `lat` and `lng`. In fetching the coordinates of the markers, I have a database for it and when calculating the coordinates. I use some formula that I  [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042418/mysql-select-coordinates-within-range).

Here is my code in backend in fetching nearby markers based on the center marker

```
Static lat lng from frontend   // lat: 1.3182001528756,lng: 103.84650707245


$km = $request->radius/1000;   //1km
$centerLat = $request->centerLat;
$centerLng = $request->centerLng;
$ky = 40000 / 360;
$originParm = $centerLat.','.$centerLng;

$test = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT school_name as name, lng, lat, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $centerLat . ") ) 
* cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $centerLng . ") ) 
+ sin( radians(" . $centerLat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM xp_pn_schools HAVING distance < ".$km.""));

$test = json_decode(collect($test),true);

foreach($test as $data) {
    $arr['data'][] = array(
        'coord' => ['lat' => $data['lat'], 'lng' => $data['lng']],
        'name' => ucwords(strtolower($data['name'])),
        'distance' => $data['distance'],

    );
    $coordArr[] = $data['lat'].','.$data['lng']; //concat for google api link
}
```

Backend for using the goole distance matrix api (For getting the ETA and distance based on the location)

```
$destination = implode('|',$coordArr);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins='.$originParm.'&destinations='.rawurlencode($destination).'&key=***********&mode=driving';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$output = json_decode($output,true);
curl_close($ch);

return response()->json(array(
                'markers' => $arr,
                'time' => $output
              ));
```

But in my frontend when i check the response, I got something like

[image]

I set the radius for 1km or 1000 from my front end in order to render little results to compare

As what you can see the first result which is `Farrer School` has a distance of `0.8 km` from the formula. But in the google maps api it is `2.1 km` . How can I verify which of the two is correct?

Comment: your select query its antquated, but correct, but don't use the actual ways to go. the distance is a straight line. an google maps uses actual street to get the distancce in that effect bith are right.

Comment: why someone downvote my question?

Comment: what do you mean? @nbk

Comment: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065116/mysql-request-for-combining-and-searching-in-2-tables/60067302#60067302) therre you can see how you get the distance much simpler than your query. Both your solution and mine wouldget the same result for the distance., second. When you use google maps and enter 2 points it comes uo with the distance, but the way follows the streets that exists. Your distance only provodes a direct way so there you find the distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The haversine formula gives great circle/straight line distance, the distance matrix gives driving distance.  Those two will almost always be different, the driving distance the larger of the two.