# MySQL select rows in Geolocation range

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation

Background information: I am making an app(school project) where users can search for an item nearby. My app uses a table of Items where all item data is stored.

I need to get the rows which are in a certain diameter(5km) of my user's current position(51.337036, 4.645095). In the Items table there is column for latitude and longitude to locate the item.

In my current query I can select the rows which are in a square(4 coordinate points) but I need to have a sphere:

```
WHERE (C.latitude BETWEEN 50 AND 52) AND (C.longitude BETWEEN 3 AND 5)
```

Is it possible to use a MySQL Geolocation variable or function?

After some research I saw a type POINT, but my table doesn't have that type (the table needs to stay the same).

Comment: 2 km from what, you need a point of orignin to get the distance

Comment: Yes indeed, the point of origin will be provided by the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS is said in the comment you have to have a point of valid origin

```
WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(-82.337036, 29.645095 ), POINT(C.`longitude`, C.`latitude` ))/1000 <= 2  AND T.difficulty = 1 AND T.terrain = 2;
```

This would give you all rows that are in max 2 km disance from POINT(-82.337036, 29.645095 )

The you have to put  your own location

Comment: Do I need to add the st_distance_sphere in the select part? Now I get an error which says that st_distance_sphere is unknown.

Comment: @tmach https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html

Comment: @Massa I checked the link, but still studio displays error('POINT' is not a recognized built-in function name) sam for ST_Distance_Sphere.

Comment: please add the code that cuases problems, you can use the st_distance_sphere everywhere you want it onpöy calaculates, buit as i mentiuoned in the answer, ou need a valid point of origin

Comment: here is also an example of the function at work https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067302/5193536