# Count locations withing given distance

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, that selects places withing given radius:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    group, 
    name,  
    111.1111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat))
       * COS(RADIANS(".$lon.") - RADIANS(t1.lon))
       + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat))))) AS distance
  FROM t1
) AS grp
WHERE distance < 10
```

Is there a way to count how many locations in each group withing this query?

Comment: can you please provide a [mre] for your wanted result and you kn ow that here a newer functions for distance https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067302/5193536

Comment: Thanks. My db MySQL version is still 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use HAVING to reduce the number of rows.

```
SELECT 
    `group`, COUNT(*) NumOfNames
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `group`,
            name,
            ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT('.$lon.', '.$lat.'), POINT(t1.lon, t1.lat)) / 1000 AS distance
    FROM
        t1
    HAVING distance < 10) t2
GROUP BY `group`
```

Comment: yes this will work on mysql 5.7 see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html if your version is too old swutch the disnace back to the old formula, it will still work